# What are the ideals of Lie algebra of upper triangular $ n \times n $ matrices over a field $F$.?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras, ideals

If we let $ \mathfrak{b}(n,F) $ be the Lie algebra of upper triangular $ n \times n $ matrices over a field $F$, then $\mathfrak{n}(n,F)$, the Lie algebra of strictly upper $ n \times n $ matrices over the field $F$ is an ideal of $ \mathfrak{b}(n,F) $.

I've tried to find all ideals of $ \mathfrak{b}(n,F) $ i.e. $(0), Z:$ the center of $ \mathfrak{b}(n,F) $, $\mathfrak{n}(n,F)$ and $ \mathfrak{b}(n,F) $ itself. What ideals remains ?

My question is - does there exist another ideals of $ \mathfrak{b}(n,F) $?

Does $S_1=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  a & b\\
  0 & 0
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$, $S_2=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  0 & b\\
  0 & c
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$ or $\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  a & b\\
  0 & a
\end{smallmatrix}\big)=Z+S_1=Z+S_2$ are ideals ?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your choice of $n$ is too small. In fact one knows that the Lie algebra of upper triangular $n$ dimensional matrices is solvable, so meaning if $\mathfrak{b}_{r+1} = [\mathfrak{b}_r, \mathfrak{b}_r]$ where $\mathfrak{b}_0= \mathfrak{b}$ one sees that the series of $\mathfrak{b}_r$-s are strictly descending and are also a chain of descending ideals in$\mathfrak b$.

Comment: If the case is $2 \times 2$ matrices.
Does it have only the 7 ideals mentioned above?